# Where can I learn how to do live queries?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, json

I'm trying to get data from MySql, parse it via php and echo it in json, then jquery will grab the new data and will update the table with the new data.

I have a basic table with basic data, I'm just trying to display my data dynamically for my users. When they select an option from the dropdown menu, the table will update with the new info.

I can grab the data and encode it to json. The problem I'm having is the jquery part. I don't know how to call the php json data and update the table.

I found datatables.net and their plugin is way more than what I need. I just need a simple example so I can start from there. Can someone show me a simple example of doing live queries?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

have you tried getting a look at 
http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/server_side.html

update:

take a look at

http://ptheart.com/beta/testdatatables.php

and let me know if this helps.

update: 
then you should try jqgrid

Comment: Yes, but like I said...that's way more than what I need.

Comment: It's the same thing as datatables. I don't want to use that.

Comment: Thumb up for Satya answer. Datatables have great documentation and forum. Everything works out of box.